# Using COALESCE in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which will update the album details if a album id is present in the table , if not it will add a new record.
User some times can update all values, or some times leaves some values. So in case if the user leave the values for updating old data should be kept in table.
For this i found solution to make use of coasesce in sql...

I wrote my SP as:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_M_Album]

   SET [AlbumName] = @AlbumName
      ,[ImageName] = @Imagename
      ,[Description] = coalesce(@Description,[Description])
      ,[Imagepath] = @Imagepath
      ,[UpdatedBy] = @CreatedBy
      ,[UpdatedDate] = @CreatedDate
      where AlbumID =@AlbumId
      end
```

If i did not send the Description the old data is not keeping, it is overriding by empty data.
Please some one help me if i have any mistakes..

Answer (score 3):

The value of `@Description` you pass is blank or empty, not `NULL`.

`COALESCE` and other null checking functions treat `''` as a non null value.

These are all true,

```
NULL IS NULL

'' IS NOT NULL

' ' IS NOT NULL
```

---

If you want to check for `NULL`, `''` (empty) or `' '` (whitespace), you could use

```
COALESCE(LEN(TRIM(@Description)), 0) = 0
```

or, for just `NULL` and empty,

```
COALESCE(LEN(@Description), 0) = 0
```

but, it would be more efficient to avoid passing empty or blank values.

---

You could rewrite your SP like this

```
IF COALESCE(LEN(TRIM(@Description)), 0) = 0
    UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_M_Album]
        SET
                 [AlbumName] = @AlbumName
                ,[ImageName] = @Imagename
                ,[Imagepath] = @Imagepath
                ,[UpdatedBy] = @CreatedBy
                ,[UpdatedDate] = @CreatedDate
        WHERE
                 [AlbumID] = @AlbumId;
 ELSE
     UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_M_Album]
        SET
                 [AlbumName] = @AlbumName
                ,[ImageName] = @Imagename
                ,[Description] = @Description
                ,[Imagepath] = @Imagepath
                ,[UpdatedBy] = @CreatedBy
                ,[UpdatedDate] = @CreatedDate
         WHERE
                 [AlbumID] = @AlbumID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the value assigned for @Description is an empty string or NULL. If you pass an empty string in @Description then that is the problem. Only passing NULL will "default" to the next non-null value (this applies to both COALESCE or ISNULL).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_M_Album]

   SET [AlbumName] = @AlbumName
      ,[ImageName] = @Imagename
      ,[Description] = Case WHEN (@Description IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(@Description) = '') 
                            THEN [Description]
                            ELSE @Description
      ,[Imagepath] = @Imagepath
      ,[UpdatedBy] = @CreatedBy
      ,[UpdatedDate] = @CreatedDate
      where AlbumID =@AlbumId
      end
```